# How to convert elevation data from WGS84 ITRF2008 to NAD83 CGG2013a

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, elevation, gdalwarp, vertical-transformation

I need to convert elevation data captured in WGS84 ITRF2008 to NAD83 CGG2013a.

I came across with [GPS-H](https://webapp.csrs-scrs.nrcan-rncan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/applications.php?locale=en) from NRCAN and downloaded the Geoid Model file (`CGG2013ai08.byn`) from [here](https://webapp.csrs-scrs.nrcan-rncan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/geoid.php?locale=en).

[image]

Although I use a CSV file above, I have to convert a DEM at the end. So I figured I use `gdalwarp` with `CGG2013i08a.tif` from [here](https://webapp.csrs-scrs.nrcan-rncan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/geoid.php?locale=en). Is this a correct approach?

```
gdal_translate -of "GTiff" dem.asc dem.tif

gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_def" ^
    -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=./CGG2013i08a.tif" ^
    -tr 6.548040000009626E-07 4.685470000003392E-07 -overwrite ^
    dem.tif dem_projected.tif

:: EPSG:1256 not working, however, since DEM is east of Ontario... use EPSG:6647
gdal_edit.py -a_srs EPSG:4326+6647 dem_projected.tif
```

I am hoping that somebody with more expertise in this area could verify that my approaches are correct, or do I miss something? And how can I do this in ArcGIS Pro or QGIS?

I was also hoping someone could elaborate what is really going on here. I am not an expert with vertical coordinate systems and it was quite challenging to figure this out so far. I'd like to understand more about it and I think that this question will help many others  also.

Comment: vdatum - https://vdatum.noaa.gov/